# UseContext() not updating my state variables and keeps track of previous

Tags: reactjs

I have a very specific issue with using Contexts in ReactJS. TLDR: I'm using two contexts, one for users that stores user details one for tasks that stores tasks details.
My user context updates the username, if a new token is registered (new login)

```html
const [username, setUserName] = useState();
  const [token, setToken] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    const user = Pool.getCurrentUser();
    if (user) {
      setUserName(user.username);
    }
  }, [token]);
```

I then have a task context, that does a fetch API call using the username from the Usercontext.
However when I look at logs, it keeps track of the previous username and updates it only on a refresh?

```html
function TasksProvider({ children }) {
  const { username } = useContext(AccountContext);
  //console.log(username);
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
  const fetchTasks = async () => {
    const result = await getAllTasks(username);
    setTodos(result);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchTasks();
  }, []);
```

Below is my context provider

```html
function ContextProvider({ children }) {
  return (
    <AccountContext>
      <CategoriesContext>
        <PathContext>
          <TasksContext>{children}</TasksContext>
        </PathContext>
      </CategoriesContext>
    </AccountContext>
  );
}
```

I basically want my TaskContext to also have the new username every time a new user log's in. Definitely not keep track of the previous username.
I have played around with states and tried to update if tokens change but can't seem to wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing `username` as a dependency in the `useEffect` call

```
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchTasks();
  }, [username]);
```

If you add this, then `fetchTasks()` will be called whenever the username changes.

You can use the eslint plugin "eslint-plugin-react-hooks" mentioned in the React docs to avoid these issues: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#eslint-plugin